# Spring Data Map Object

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I need to join 2 tables and return data in JSON. For this thought in a HashMap, but I do not know how to do.

### User

```
@Entity
public class User {
    //...
}
```

### Profile

```
@Entity
public class Profile {
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    //...
}
```

### Repositories

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
//...
}

public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Profile, Long>{
//...
}
```

I need the number of profiles per user in a list.

```
John 0
Victor 2
Maria 4
...
```

### What better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping table and use that table to join both table:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable
(
      name="USER_PROFILE",
      joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
      inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="PROFILE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}
)
private List<Profile> profileList;
```

USER_PROFILE table:

- USER_ID     number
- PROFILE_ID  number

When you get user list, you can iterate it and get profile list for each of them:

```
ArrayList<User> userList = UserRepository .findAll();
for(user:userList)
{
     user.getProfileList().size();  //You can get size for each user
}
```